# Default Ruby not loading with RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Not sure if this issue is related to a recent Oh-My-ZSH update, but all of a sudden, my RVM default Ruby is not loading when opening a new Terminal window (instead, it loads the system Ruby).

I have added `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to about every dotfile on my system (.zshrc, .zprofile, .zlogin, .profile, even .bashrc and .bash_profile for good measure).

RVM is loading when the session starts (I can manually switch to the default with `rvm default`), and `$HOME/.rvm/bin` is in my $PATH.  If I switch to a directory with a .ruby-version and/or .ruby-gemset file, it loads that Ruby.

EDIT:
To clarify, my problem is that the default Ruby I declared with RVM (`rvm use <RUBY VERSION> --default`) is not being loaded when I start a new terminal session or when I `cd` out of a directory that has a .ruby-version file.

EDIT #2:
Here is the results of `rvm list`

```
{15:20}[]~ ➭ rvm list

rvm rubies

ruby-1.9.3-p550 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.0.0-p594 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.1.3 [ x86_64 ]
* ruby-2.1.4 [ x86_64 ]
```

Comment: that's the point of `.ruby-version` or a `.rvmrc` file in a project, that way the project is being run with the same dependencies and versions across all machines.

Comment: @Anthony I understand what the .ruby-version file does.  That is not the issue.  I merely pointed that out to demonstrate that RVM itself is being loaded and is working as expected when I initiate a new terminal session.  The problem is the default Ruby I declared is not being loaded when I start a new session; instead the system default (Mac OSX included) Ruby is.

Comment: What is the output when you do `rvm list`? What version has the `*` next to it (i..e `#  * - default`)

Answer (score 2):

So I half figured this out.  I was attempting to set a default Ruby with the global gemset for that particular Ruby version (`rvm use 2.1.4@global --default`).  When I set the default without the gemset, it persists and is loaded in each subsequent session.

In the past I have been able to load the default with a gemset.  Not sure if this is an issue with the latest version of oh-my-zsh or rvm.

Comment: I had the same issue, and used this post to make oh-my-zsh honor the default rvm ruby instead of system ruby... Great so far, but still whould like to do what you wanted. 'rvm use 2.2.2@global --default' but if I do so, then the new shell/terminal defaults to using System ruby... Did you figure this out?