# RVM default ruby not used when opening terminal

Tags: ruby, rvm, gnome-terminal

This issue seems to relate to [Default Ruby not loading with RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867714/default-ruby-not-loading-with-rvm), but the answer do not help me.

On my Ubuntu 14 LTS, I've got 2 rubies installed in rvm and set 2.2-head as default using `rvm use 2.2-head --default`. After reopening terminal (login shell is configured) 2.2 does not get set as *current*

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.2-head [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I couldn't find any `.ruby-version` or `.rvmrc` in current ($HOME) folder (or its parents).
Meanwhile I tried removing *system* ruby (1.9.3), but this has no effect, too.
What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem could be solved by **rebooting** system, although I don't know why this works

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions on https://rvm.io/rubies/default?

Comment: Yes. Like mentioned in the question I've referred to, the problem is "that the default Ruby I declared with RVM (rvm use <RUBY VERSION> --default) is not being loaded when I start a new terminal session [...]".