# Ubuntu ruby version keeps changing even after specifying default version in rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I want to use ruby 2.3.4 for my rails application which I have installed using rvm on Ubuntu 16.04.

after using command **`rvm list`**.

> ```
> rvm rubies
>
> =* ruby-2.3.4 [ x86_64 ]
>
> # => - current
> # =* - current && default
> #  * - default
> ```

but when i use **`ruby -v`** I get.

> ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]

so I used **`rvm --default use 2.3.4`**.

which does change the version to 2.3.4 when I check using **`ruby -v`** but when I restart the terminal or system it changes back to **`2.5.0`**

I want to know how to include **`2.5.0`** into `rvm` or remove it.

Comment: Remove the system-wide version with `sudo apt-get remove ruby`.

Comment: @mudasobwa tried that but I get *Package 'ruby' is not installed, so not removed*

Comment: Then check you have no `rbenv` or any other concurrent ruby version manager installed.

Comment: Can you see if this works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867714/default-ruby-not-loading-with-rvm?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @mudasobwa checking into system files it seems its taking version from file **.rbenv/version**

Comment: @mudasobwa setting rvm as default instead of rbenv solved the issue for me

Comment: Cool then. To install `ruby 2.5`` into `rvm` if you still want to do so use `rvm install ruby 2.5.0`.

Comment: Can you see where Ruby 2.5.0 is installed, use `which ruby`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that `.bash_profile` contains below lines:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Check `.bashrc, .zshrc, .mkshrc` file contains below lines at end of file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

if not then,

First Run below command then follow link to install rvm:

```
rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

[RVM Install](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#explained)